# I can't close completely PyQt5 script

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I run the following script, named test2.py, if I click on Ok or Cancel button the window closes but I don't get the prompt. I think I forgot something stupid ...

This is the test2.py script:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import sys
import unittest

class MainAppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        dialog = Qt.QDialog()
        
        buttonbox = Qt.QDialogButtonBox(Qt.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | Qt.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        
        param_box = Qt.QGroupBox('Iterate over parameters:')

        pblayout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        pblayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        scroll = Qt.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setFrameStyle(scroll.NoFrame)
        scroll.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        pblayout.addWidget(scroll)

        param_lay = Qt.QGridLayout()

        wid = Qt.QWidget()
        
        scroll.setWidget(wid)

        wid.setLayout(param_lay)

        param_box.setLayout(pblayout)

        layout.addWidget(param_box)
        layout.addWidget(buttonbox)

        dialog.setLayout(layout)

        buttonbox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
        buttonbox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

        param_lay.addWidget(Qt.QLabel('iter. / database:'), 0, 0, 1, 3)
        param_lay.addWidget(Qt.QLabel('iter.:'), 0, 3, 1, 2)
        param_lay.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        param_lay.setColumnStretch(4, 1)
        param_lay.setRowStretch(0, 0)
 
        res = dialog.exec_()

        if res != dialog.Accepted:
            print('dialog not accepted')
        else:
            print('dialog accepted')




if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainAppWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run the script with `python3 test2.py`, I observe in stdout the `dialog accepted` or `dialog not accepted` depending on the button clicked, the window closes but I don't get the prompt. I have to stop manually (CtrLZ) to get the prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 eventloops: `dialog.exec_()`  and `app.exec_()` so when the first eventloop finishes the other eventloop starts. On the other hand, it is useless to create a class that inherits from MainAppWindow since the window is never used or shown.

One possible solution is to start only one eventloop:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QGridLayout,
    QGroupBox,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QScrollArea,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


def main():
    dialog = QDialog()

    buttonbox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

    layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)

    param_box = QGroupBox("Iterate over parameters:")

    pblayout = QVBoxLayout()
    pblayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    scroll = QScrollArea()
    scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll.setFrameStyle(scroll.NoFrame)
    scroll.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    pblayout.addWidget(scroll)

    param_lay = QGridLayout()

    wid = QWidget()

    scroll.setWidget(wid)

    wid.setLayout(param_lay)

    param_box.setLayout(pblayout)

    layout.addWidget(param_box)
    layout.addWidget(buttonbox)

    buttonbox.accepted.connect(dialog.accept)
    buttonbox.rejected.connect(dialog.reject)

    param_lay.addWidget(QLabel("iter. / database:"), 0, 0, 1, 3)
    param_lay.addWidget(QLabel("iter.:"), 0, 3, 1, 2)
    param_lay.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
    param_lay.setColumnStretch(4, 1)
    param_lay.setRowStretch(0, 0)

    res = dialog.exec_()

    if res != dialog.Accepted:
        print("dialog not accepted")
    else:
        print("dialog accepted")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```